# caching mysql query returned by Python script

Tags: python, mysql, performance, caching

I have this python '2.6.4' script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import csv
import pprint

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # The Host
                     user="username", # username
                      passwd="password", # password
                      db="dbname") # name of the data base

cursor = db.cursor() 

cursor.execute("SELECT name, id, city, storeid FROM Products;")

StudentsData = cursor.fetchall()
pprint.pprint(StudentsData)
```

this query return millions of rows, and it takes `3 minutes` to execute, and it run 20 times a day, and everyuser has to wait three minutes to fetch the output.

I was thinking about `caching` it, but I don't know how to do that in python, 
will that be a good idea, if so how can I do it, using the obove code.

please help me if there's  a better way to do this?

Comment: The decision of whether to cache is entirely up to you.  Will stale data be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decision of whether to cache is entirely up to you. Will stale data be a problem?

The simplest caching scheme I can think of is something like the following using Python's [**pickle module**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```py
import MySQLdb
import csv
import pprint
import time

MAX_CACHE_AGE = 60*20  # 20 Minutes
CACHE_FILENAME = 'results.cache'

with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'r') as cache:
    cached = pickle.load(cache)

if(time.time() > cached['timestamp'] + MAX_CACHE_AGE):
    # Cache too old, run query
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # The Host
                     user="username", # username
                     passwd="password", # password
                     db="dbname") # name of the data base

    cursor = db.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, id, city, storeid FROM Products;")
    StudentsData = cursor.fetchall()

    # Update cache file
    data = {'results': StudentsData, 'timestamp':time.time()}
    with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'w') as cache:
        pickle.dump(data, cache)

else:
    # Cached data is fresh enough, use that
    StudentsData = cached['results']

pprint.pprint(StudentsData)
```

You'll need to initialize the `results.cache` file once manually.

---

***EDIT***

The `with` syntax is a context manager and was introduced in Python 2.5.

```
with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'r') as cache:
    cached = pickle.load(cache)
```

Can be rewritten as

```
cached = open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'r')
cached = pickle.load(cache)
cached.close()
```

---

***EDIT2***

After a long discussion in chat, the following works:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
import pprint
import time
import pickle

MAX_CACHE_AGE = 60*20  # 20 Minutes
CACHE_FILENAME = 'results.cache'

regen = False
try:
    with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'r') as cache:
        cached = pickle.load(cache)

    if(time.time() > cached['timestamp'] + MAX_CACHE_AGE):
        print("Cache too old: regenerating cache")
        regen = True
    else:
        print("Cached data is fresh enough: loading results from cache")

except IOError:
    print("Error opening %s: regenerating cache" % CACHE_FILENAME)
    regen = True

if(regen):
    # Cache too old, run query
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # The Host
                     user="username", # username
                     passwd="password", # password
                     db="dbname") # name of the data base

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, id, city, storeid FROM Products;")
    StudentsData = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()

    # Update cache file
    data = {'results': StudentsData, 'timestamp':time.time()}
    with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'w') as cache:
        pickle.dump(data, cache)

else:
    # Cached data is fresh enough, use that
    StudentsData = cached['results']


print StudentsData
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great example!! I believe that this is exactly what I'm looking for, the only thing is that I get this error,     `with open(CACHE_FILENAME, 'r') as cache:
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
should I install something for the script to work? Thanks!

Comment: Did you miss the `as` in there?

Comment: I got the error with and without as . I tried to remove it and see if that will solve the issue. but it didn't.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  A version before context managers were supported?  I edited in an alternative pattern in case you're using Python < 2.5

Comment: sorry, I didn't post that. `'2.6.4'`

Comment: Then the with syntax should work fine.  Could you double check that you copied everything correctly?

Comment: Try to change it to the pattern without `with` statements I added at the end of the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27351/discussion-between-mongotop-and-jedwards)

Comment: it works like magic!!! thank you very much jedwards for your great help and highly appreciated patient and support!!!

Comment: Is this method susceptible to data races? How are they handled?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, and for a very simple case, you could look at functools.lru_cache: http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

For more sophisticated caching, Beaker is probably the way to go: http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/caching.html

Comment: Any alternatives for python2??